# How to use raw .html files in sphinx-build

Tags: python-sphinx

Let's say I have this structure in my source folder for my sphinx documentation :

```
journals /
  *.md files
reports /
  *.html files
conf.py
index.rst
```

and the following code in index.rst :

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 4
   :glob:
   :caption: Reports

   reports/*

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 4
   :glob:
   :caption: Journals

   journals/*
```

When I generate my docs with sphinx-build, sphinx automatically builds the resulting html pages with the .md files found in my `journals` folder, but it ignores the .html files found in the `reports` folder.
What I would like is for sphinx to automatically include the .html files found in the `reports` folder. The resulting .html pages should still include the sphinx layout (sidebar, headers, etc.), and should not just be a pure copy of the raw .html files.

I know I could do .rst files with the following :

```
.. raw:: html
   :file: reports/file.html
```

This basically does what I want. The .rst file is found by sphinx and builds a .html file that includes both sphinx layout and my source .html file.
I just don't know how to do this automatically though, as I have a lot of files in my reports file. I would prefer to avoid having to create one .rst file for each of my .html file.

Is there a way to automatize this process with sphinx-build?

Comment: No. You could write a script to do this, but I reckon it would be faster to do it manually.